# How to select only the lines that appears once based in two columns?

Tags: shell, awk, sh

I have a file with this pattern:

`start: 1 elapsed: 1 suite: path.to.class case: method`

I want to print the entire value of line where the concatenation of `suite` and `case` values appears only once. Example:

**input**

```
start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class case: sampleMethod1
start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class case: sampleMethod2
start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class case: sampleMethod2
start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class case: sampleMethod3
start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class case: sampleMethod3
start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class2 case: sampleMethod1
start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class2 case: sampleMethod1
```

**expected output**

`start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class case: sampleMethod1`

This is very similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261007/print-only-unique-lines-from-file-not-the-duplicates) question, however, in that, it only prints columns where the equality is being checked. My best attempt is:

`awk '{arr[$6,$8]++} END {for (i in arr) {if (arr[i]==1) {print $0} }}' filename`

but it prints: `start: 1 elapsed: 2 suite: com.path.class2 case: sampleMethod1`

Comment: What's your question? The fields you want to examine are apparently `$6` and `$8`. You can concatenate them in an index key with `arr[$6 $8]` and if you want a separator between them, just add one, like `arr[$6 ":" $8]`

Comment: How can I print the entire value of line where the concatenation of "suite" and "case" columns appears only once

Comment: In the `END` block, `$0` is the last line in the file, so your updated attempt will simply print the final line as many times as there were matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea. Instead of incrementing a counter, set the array value for this key to the line (maybe line number and file name too), and when you see a key you have already seen before, change it to a sentinel value. I chose the number zero because it conveniently evaluates to "not true" in boolean context.

```
awk '($6 ":" $8 in arr) { arr[$6 ":" $8] = 0; next }
    { arr[$6 ":" $8] = FILENAME ":" NR ":" $0 }
    END { for (k in arr) if (arr[k]) print arr[k] }' file
```

If we see a key we have seen before, change its value in the array to zero. The `next` skips the rest of the script for the current line. If we fall through, this is the first occurrence of this key, so collect the information we want to print if we don't see it again. When we are done reading, print the nonzero entries.

Comment: Cool, it will take me sometime to digest all of that but it seems to work! Thanks!